# google map v3 removing dotted borders

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am from India. I am using Google map API v3 in my application. Is there any way I can remove the dotted dotted border between India, Pakistan and China? Using the v2 API it was easy because I just connected to Google's India server instead of .com.

Like http://maps.google.co.in is not showing that dotted line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do exactly the same thing with Version 3:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.co.in/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

Loading the API from `.co.in` servers will use the Indian maps.

Comment: Thank you very much u saved my time actually I was struggling because I was using http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js I got this from google tutorial when I changed it to http://maps.googleapis.co.in/maps/api/js it was not working. Now I used the source given by you, thanQ you very much Andrew.

Comment: @weapon It works at the moment, and Google may maintain it as the way to get country-specific maps. Or they may change the URL to use the googleapis domain. Keep an eye on the documentation.